# EditorFor() throws NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this Model:

```
public class PhoneViewModel
{

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string CountryCode
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

In the view I have 
@model PhoneViewModel
.
.
.
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber);
.
.
.

I've got NullReferenceException when EditorFor is called.
I've verified that Html is not null. The Model that is passed in is also not null.
If I replace EditorFor with TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber), I no longer get the NullReferenceException.

Here's the stack trace:

Event Name: UnhandledException

An unhandled exception has occured in the site.

> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Cause: Unknown.
>   Instructions: Contact dev.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 cacheLocator, Func`2 locator)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor[TContainer,TValue](HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor[TModel,TValue](HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression)
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .

I can't figure out what would cause the null reference exception here. Any help would be really appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: Do you have any custom EditorTemplates defined? Those will be in a special folder in Views/Shared.

Comment: Some more code could help here. What does your controller look like?

Comment: interesting. never experienced this before. have you tried with a plain brand new solution and MVC project? What happens when you do this?

Comment: Can you post the relevant controller action and view please?